# Play infinitely looping video on-load in HTML5

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm looking to place a video in an HTML5 page that will begin playing on page-load, and once completed, loop back to the beginning without a break. The video should also **NOT** have any controls associated with it, and either be compatible with all 'modern' browsers, or have the option of a polyfill.

Previously I would have done this via `Flash` and `FLVPlayback`, but I would prefer to steer clear of `Flash` in the HTML5 sphere. I'm thinking I could use javascript's `setTimeout` to create a smooth loop, but what should I use to embed the video itself? Is there something out there that will stream the video the way `FLVPlayback` would?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

The `loop` attribute should do it:

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The addition of the unintuitive `muted` attribute is required by Chrome as [documented on their dev site](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/).

Should you have a problem with the loop attribute (as we had in the past), listen to the `videoEnd` event and call the `play()` method when it fires.

Note1: I'm not sure about the behavior on Apple's iPad/iPhone, because they have some restrictions against `autoplay`.

Note2: `loop="true"` and  `autoplay="autoplay"` are deprecated

Comment: Indeed good advice sir. I ended up using `javascript` to listen for the `videoEnd` event, and looping back to the beginning as from what I can tell, the `loop` attribute is not supported by all browsers. For iOS devices, they don't support `autoplay` in any way shape or form by iOS 5, so I just used a fallback image for mobile. Thanks again.

Comment: using <video loop="true"> is **invalid** http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/video.html - either use <video loop="loop"> or just <video loop> - this rule hold for almost ALL HTML5 tags (either just tagname, or tagname="tagname" for XHTML5)

Comment: @vaxquis thanks for update, you are welcome to edit api changes next time!

Comment: No problem, mate, always happy to help. Still, I wouldn't mix XHTML-type attributes 'autoplay="autoplay"' with HTML-type 'loop' - I'd go with with either <video ... autoplay loop>, parsable as HTML5 or <video ... autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">, parsable as either HTML5 or XHTML5. mixing styles makes a markup that's still invalid as XHTML but unnecessarily verbose for HTML.

Comment: Generally, `autoplay` only works in Safari if you also use `muted`: https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/

Comment: This is not part of the question but someone asked me how to easyly make it responsive so I did this with a 800px video width:

`<div style="max-width:800px: height:auto">
    <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay loop>
        <source src="http://mumu.com.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/formas-animadas.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>`

Comment: Related [autoplay muted looping video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59377946/1717535)

Comment: I would suggest to style it like [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/UtmostCreator/gktp28wc/)

Answer (score 63):

As of April 2018, Chrome (along with several other major browsers) now [require](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) the `muted` attribute too.

Therefore, you should use

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 25):

For iPhone it works if you add also playsinline so:

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Props for JSX: `autoPlay loop muted playsInline`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this the following two ways:

1) Using `loop` attribute in video element (mentioned in the first answer):

2) and you can use the `ended` media event:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var newVideo = document.getElementById('videoElementId');
    newVideo.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    }, false);

    newVideo.play();

});
```