# jQuery autoplay video

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I have some very basic HTML for a video:

```
<div class="video_holder">
      <video id="video_player" controls="controls" poster=""> 
        <source id="video_mp4" src="" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
      </video>
</div>
```

in my js:

```
 function playFile(e) {
      ...
      e.preventDefault()
      var selected = $(this);
      var path = selected.attr('href');
      $("#video_mp4").attr('src', path);
      // how do I get this thing to auto-play?????
  };
```

This works great for injecting the correct path into the `src` attribute, and I have verified the path is correct and accessible. However, I cannot get the video to autoplay on load.

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("video_player").play();

$('#video_player').trigger('play');

$('#video_player').play();
```

How can I trigger the video to autoplay?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("#video_player")[0].play();
```

Or:

```
$("#video_player")[0].autoplay = true;
```

Or:

```
document.getElementById("video_player").setAttribute('autoplay', true);
```

Whatever suits you. Using `$('#video_player').play();` you are referencing to non-existing method `play` in jQuery and you should reference to the object found by `$("#video_player")`.

To change the src of the video in JS, you just simply need something like that:

```
function playFile() {
    var video = $("#video_player");
    video[0].src = "http://www.yoursrc.com/video_new.mp4";
    video[0].load();
    video[0].play();
};
```

---

**NOTE:**
In Chrome, you should also need to add `muted` property if you want to use the `autoplay` attribute. Refer to : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Actually non of these methods worked for me. Is there something wrong with my html? The link definitely works, if I hardcode it.

Comment: It seems as though the video is not updated, because if I hardcode the  link, I can trigger play with jQuery but it always plays the hardcoded video, even when the `src` element is updated.

Comment: @DarwinTech, I've edited my answer. If you have trouble with JS the best way to debug your code is using `console.log()` inside your code. This will output everything you want in console of your browser. For example, in my code above you can debug the `video` variable like that: `console.log(video);` and you will see the whole object and its methods and parameters in the console. It's really great tool. If you will have any problem with that tool/code feel free to ask.

Comment: Turned out that `$("#video_player")[0].load();` is necessary before calling `play()`, at least in my case. @sobol6803 - if you want to add that to your answer I'll accept it, as the rest was correct.

Comment: This worked for me, however, I had to call `.load()` before `.play()`, like @DarwinTech said.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of **a video that will cover the whole window and autoplay, on a loop**. It's created on demand via JavaScript.

I needed this for a video that should **only load and play when requested**, i.e. not on every load of the page. (Hiding the element with `display: none;` won't do, because the video then still loads even if not displayed.)

## JavaScript

```
/**
 * Create the video.
 *
 * An alternative might have been to use an HTML template tag inside the Twig template,
 * to then create an element and append it. But this worked only in Chrome:
 * - in Firefox, `autoplay loop muted` (inside the <template>) get converted to
 *   `autoplay="" loop="" muted=""` (in the Inspector) and there's no playback.
 * - in Safari, nothing happens.
 *
 * Another alternative (that worked this one) is to just append the whole HTML as a
 * single string, but it's harder to read.
 */
var video = $('<video />', {
    id: 'video',
    class: 'myclass',
    poster: 'https://path/to/my/poster.jpg'
}).prop({
    muted: true,
    autoplay: true,
    loop: true,
});
var src1 = $('<source />', {
    type: 'video/webm', // for Firefox, Chrome; slightly smaller file size
    src: 'https://path/to/my/video.webm'
}).appendTo(video);
var src2 = $('<source />', {
    type: 'video/mp4', // for Safari, Firefox, Chrome
    src: 'https://path/to/my/video.mp4'
}).appendTo(video);
video.appendTo($('body'));
```

Note that:

- **`muted`, `autoplay`, `loop` must go inside of `prop()`**. Setting them as attributes will **not** work! (And will be quite misleading, because you'd think you set them when in fact you really haven't.)
- **`muted`** is needed in Chrome for `autoplay` to work.
- A simple way to create the poster: open the video with VLC, take a `Snapshot`, converted the resulting PNG to JPG.
- Make sure the video is properly converted. Not all MP4 files will work in the browser. This proved useful: [Video conversion with FFmpeg (for the Web)](https://gist.github.com/jaydenseric/220c785d6289bcfd7366).

The hard-to-read-alternative mentioned above:

```
$('body').append('<video class="c-congrats  c-congrats--outofnew" autoplay loop muted> <source src="https://path/to/my/video.webm" type="video/webm" /> <source src="https://path/to/my/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> Your browser does not support the video tag. </video>')
```

## CSS

```
.myclass {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this simple step, This works well for me

```
$('video').trigger('play');
```

Thanks