# Create a new html5 video object with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, video

How can you create a video element with jQuery, and add it's properties like control to true (`<video control>`), add and remove video sources (`<source src='http://somesite.com/somevideo.mp4'`), etc?

I would like to set all it's options before loading (like autoplay, true or false, etc)

I tried this without success (It worked with images, but not video):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var photo = $('<img />', {
              id: 'photo',
              src: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/',
              alt: ''
              });
photo.appendTo($('#gallery'));

var video = document.createElement('video');
    alert( video.toSource() ); //For testing
    video.id = 'video';
    video.source.src = 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4';
    video.type = 'video/mp4';
    video.control = true;
video.appendTo($('#gallery'));
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9cnaz3ju/1/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this:

```
var video = $('<video />', {
    id: 'video',
    src: 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4',
    type: 'video/mp4',
    controls: true
});
video.appendTo($('#gallery'));
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9cnaz3ju/2/)**

```js
    var photo = $('<img />', {
        id: 'photo',
        src: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/',
        alt: ''
    });
    photo.appendTo($('#gallery'));

    var video = $('<video />', {
        id: 'video',
        src: 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4',
        controls: true
    });
    video.appendTo($('#gallery'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery"></div>
```

Just follow the same basic format as your see with the image element.

Comment: Beware. If you want this to autoplay you'll need to set the property via `prop()` (and *not* along with the id attribute) cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59377946/1717535