# How can I parse through a url to get a filename

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to extract just the filename from a url as part of an ajax call but I am unable to get it to format the text correctly. It seems like it should be easy, what am I missing. I looked through responses to similar questions but nothing that worked for me... It is now duplicating the source tag -

```
AJAX
var dir = "videos/";
var fileextension = ".mp4";
var videos = $.ajax({
//This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is 
configured as 'browsable'
   url: dir,
   success: function (data) {
      //List all .mp4 file names in the page
      $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () 
           {
             var filename = $(this).attr("href").replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
             $("#container").append("<div><video id='video1' class='vidarray' preload='none' poster='bkg.png'><src='"+ filename +"'></video></div>");
    });
  }
});
```

After using suggested code, I added the new return:

```
<src='comm_7054.mp4'></src='comm_7054.mp4'>
```

Comment: you should refer to the current element in `each()` like `$(this)`

Comment: `<src='"+ filename +"'>` what sort of tag is this meant to be?   If you use `.append` jquery will parse it and you get `<src=..></src=...>` because the name of the tag is `src=..` try `$(#container").html("<div><video...`  (except that will replace what's already there of course...so might not be what you're after)

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL Why? There's no need for that.  `this.href` and `$(this).prop("href")` may give slightly different values depending on browser, but there's no reason to **always** refer to the current element in `each()` as `$(this)` - `this` will be fine in many cases.

Comment: Thanks Freedomn... I believe you are saying that I do not need to use the <src tag? I have always used src outside of the video tag. I will try it without when I get the chance. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var dir = "videos/";
var fileextension = ".mp4";
var videos = $.ajax({
//This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is 
configured as 'browsable'
   url: dir,
   success: function (data) {
      //List all .mp4 file names in the page
      $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () 
           {
             var filename = $(this).attr("href").replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
             var video = $('<video />', {
                 id: 'video1',
                 class:'vidarray',
                 preload:'none',
                 poster: 'bkg.png'
                 src: filename,
                 type: 'video/mp4',
                 controls: true
              });
video.appendTo($("#container"));
    });
  }
});
```

you can also replase `$(this).attr(...` for `$(this).prop(...` they return a string containing the content of `href`

I modify my answer using this question: [Create a new html5 video object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547855/create-a-new-html5-video-object-with-jquery), you will need to tweak it to fit what you need, but is the correct way to go...

Comment: This almost works, it is now duplicating the source tag for each item like this. <src='comm_7054.mp4'></src='comm_7054.mp4'>

Comment: @KevMoe , I edited my answer, check if it works better.