# Muted Autoplay in Chrome still not working

Tags: video, html5-video

I am having trouble getting chrome to autoplay a video. I have set the video to muted and it auto plays in both Safari and Firefox but not chrome.

```
            <video autoplay muted poster="path to video" id="bgvid">

        <source src="assets/uploads/hero/livePhotoNoSound.mp4" type="video/webm">

            <source src="assets/uploads/hero/livePhotoNoSound.mp4" type="video/mp4">

        </video>
```

I want to video to start playing automatically. Currently the video loads, but is just still. Everything I've read says that as long as it's muted it should play, but that is not the result I'm getting.

Comment: Can you post some working code to test functionality (at least in Firefox and Chrome)?

Comment: I updated the code above with the paths. Is that what you meant?

Comment: The Code here should work, but make sure data saver is not on. If data saver is on this will not play.

Comment: Data Saver is not on. This still won't work in my chrome, or any chrome for that matter. I ended up using jQuery to force the video to play. Probably not the best solution but it worked for now.
        $("#bgvid")[0].play();

Comment: It could also have been a problem with the video… Ran into a similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59377946/1717535 fixed without having to rely on events / .play.

Comment: In my case I use the attributes "preload muted autoplay loop" and I see that the autoplay works sometimes. It's randomly. And the loop does also not work. (webm). In Chromium and Firefox it works. But Chrome (v80) not. It smells like a bug. Update: I thinks it's a problem with Angular AOT build. (in my case.)

Comment: You need to use `autoPlay`, not `autoplay`.

Answer (score 42):

Although @richard-lindner's solution didn't work for me, it put me on the right track.

In my case, although the `muted` attribute was present, Chrome was ignoring it and failing silently unless it was also explicitly set in javacript e.g.

```
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
video.oncanplaythrough = function() {
    video.muted = true;
    video.play();
}
```

Interestingly, forcing the autoplay using javascript but ommitting the `video.muted = true` line did display the autoplay policy error in the console, suggesting Chrome is indeed ignoring the `muted` attribute in some cases. This to me feels like a bug with Chrome's autoplay policy.

Note that the error occurred only when the video was not cached. If it was cached, autoplay worked as expected.

Comment: Worked for me. They are really making this difficult.

Comment: Thank you. This solves the problem. And you are right, it looks like a bug.

Comment: Strangely, this seems to be a problem even with VideoJS. I have the latest version currently, 7.2.3. Calling `player.volume()` in VideoJS's callback doesn't work without that `video.muted = true`, where `video` is the video element.

Comment: +1. I can confirm that simply assigning the 'muted' attribute in HTML did not work for me, but adding the explicit property assignment suggested by @Jonny Green did work.

Comment: It disgusts me that this works perfectly. It's like Google Chrome are trying to be the next version of IE8...

Comment: tnx man, you're a life/time saver!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `oncanplay="this.muted=true"` on your video tag

```
<video  muted loop autoplay oncanplay="this.muted=true">
    <source src="your src" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Answer (score 3):

Main answer worked with me - but just in case anyone is trying to get it to work on apple phones you must use the "playsinline" attribute for it to work. for example:

```html
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="xen.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Answer (score 2):

The example below, with minimal change from your code, plays in chrome (Version 62.0.3202.94 ) on a Mac (10.12.6):

```html
<video autoplay muted poster="path to video" id="bgvid">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

It may be that Safari and Friefox are playing the mp4 and chrome the webm, and the issue related to the webm video itself rather than your HTML5 code.

Comment: I'm able to view your video above in chrome, but even as I put that exact same code into my site, Chrome refuses to play it. It's frustrating because there are no errors. Just won't work in my site for whatever reason.

Comment: If it is the exact same as the code above including the video URL, then it sounds like your site may have some more complex video player in use which is looking for the video element in the page and managing the playback.

Comment: I get exactly the same issue using no third party video player

Comment: @timstermatic - do you mean the code snippet above will not work? I just tried it again in a Chrome browser and it plays fine for me.

Comment: @mick, I meant when I put the above code in my own page. However I figured out my issue. The video is in a slider and you can't autoplay video that is in a DOM element that has been mutated. If I run the example in a  boilerplate HTML template it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

For those creating  elements in JavaScript, here is the JavaScript function I'm using to configure  elements to autoplay properly in Chrome:

```
function configureVideoElementForAutoplay (videoElement) {
  videoElement.setAttribute('playsinline', '');
  videoElement.setAttribute('muted', '');
  videoElement.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
  videoElement.muted = true;
}
```

Example:

```
let vid = document.createElement('video');
configureVideoElementForAutoplay(vid);
```

Credit to @Jonny Green for pointing out the necessity of the direct 'muted' property assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Mine wasnt working but changing the "autoplay" to "autoPlay" made Chrome (v102) play the muted video fine.

So my final code is

```
  <video width="720" height="640" autoPlay muted>
         <source src="/assets/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
         Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

I noticed this because chrome was throwing this console error:

```
Unknown DOM property autoplay. Did you mean autoPlay?
```