# Open and play YouTube in the Browser from script on Windows

Tags: powershell, browser, youtube

From a windows PowerShell script, I would like to open YouTube in a browser and play a certain video. However, I can only get it to open, but not to play. Is there any way to do this?

This is one of these questions where you only know if it is on-topic once you know the answer, so sorry about that. But in the sense of not falling into the AB problem trap, I'll just ask for what I'm trying and assume there is a programming answer. I could imagine the answer is:

- There is an API to open an URL and then execute some JavaScript
- There is a browser-specific way to do this
- There is a parameter to add to a YouTube URL (I believe they removed this due to rickrolling...)

Comment: You can only autoplay videos while muted. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638344/muted-autoplay-in-chrome-still-not-working

Answer (score 1):

well, if i do this, in powershell, i get myself rickrolled:

```
start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
```