# Looping HTML5 video with Rails and HAML video_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, video, haml

I'm using Rails video_tag to render a video as so:

```
= video_tag("SMR_video.mp4", :controls => false, :autobuffer => true, :autoplay => true, :loop => true, :id => "hero-video")
```

This results in the following, the video doesn't loop:

```
<video autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay" id="hero-video" loop="loop" src="/assets/SMR_video.mp4"></video>
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can just use `<video loop>`. I'm not sure how to generate this with haml, but if it works in html you are closer to finding the problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10415231/4018167

---

If this does not work, play with your page in different browsers. If you are using an old browser, it might work with the depricated `<video loop='true'>`