# automatically playing audio and video file in HTML

Tags: html, webkit, qwebkit

In HTML5 what special code need be to written which allows web-browser's to start playing video/audio automatically?

In fact I'm looking for signal or workaround by which I can know when webkit is about to play video/audio file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following question has been answered in another post on Stack overflow. Check out the following link:

[Play infinitely looping video on-load in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377453/play-infinitely-looping-video-on-load-in-html5)

Using the above code your video should run automatically when your page loads.