# html video background not looping

Tags: html, background, html5-video

My video bg is setup like this:

```
   <video autoplay loop poster id="bgvid" class="hidden-xs">
      <source src="bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

The bg.mp4 is about 1 minute long. On localhost, it freezes in the same spot everytime. Is this because of video length, or an error in my syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked if the video is corrupted?

Comment: what browser are you using?
if chrome, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088364/html5-video-will-not-loop/9549404#9549404

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377453/play-infinitely-looping-video-on-load-in-html5

Comment: Could it have to do with having no value for the poster attribute?

Comment: I just tried removing poster attribute. edited question. no luck yet. checking post on chrome

Comment: video was corrupt. odd issue. thanks for noticing. @Someone if you write that as the answer i will mark it correct. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if the video is corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest seeing if your video is corrupt first.