# Cross browser video autoplay loop

Tags: javascript, loops, video

I have a copy of a mp4 video which I want to show on my website and I want to know how is it possible with javascript to autoplay and loop for ever the video.
I want to make it compatible with all browsers.
I want to load the video on load of the page with js

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play infinitely looping video on-load in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377453/play-infinitely-looping-video-on-load-in-html5)

Answer (score 0):

```
<video autoplay loop>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

You mean this?

Comment: Will this play in all browsers?

Comment: Yes u can check this but I`m sure. But u know in some countries are people wtih still using IE5 and that won't work with IE5.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to mute the video (adding the `muted` attribute on the `<video>` tag) as videos with sound don’t autoplay in all browsers. Then also add the attributes `autoplay` and `playsinline`. Also you can use the `videoEnd` event and call `play()` to ensure it loops.