# Make a video 10h long while keeping it lightweight in filesize

Tags: unix, ffmpeg

I created an mp4 file with no sound that is 0:17 minutes long. I also have this mp3 file that is 3mins long.

I'd like to make a 10h video with those two, while keeping the filesize small. (8-15mb).

Is there a way to achieve that with ffmpeg?

Comment: What should happen when the 3 minute long MP3 file ends and when the 17 minute long video ends?

Comment: Do you mean playing the video and the audio in a loop? What player do you intend to use?

Comment: @llogan the music shouldnt stop. i dont care if the music stops abruptly after 10 hours. Also, I intend of using an html5 video player for this. all of the things I tried generated really big files.

Comment: also its 17 seconds lol

Answer (score 1):

Loop the 17 second video so it can match the duration of the 3 minute long audio:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -preset slow -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Then use the [HTML5 loop attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10377453/).

If you really want a 10 hour video:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i video.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -preset slow -t 10:00:00 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

File will be big and it will take a long time to encode...because it's 10 hours. Not much you can do about that.